# how does the recursive function in the result function works?

Tags: c++, recursion

I was confused by the return functions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int result(int n)
{
    if (n <= 10) {
        return n;
    }
    else {
        int a = n % 10;
        cout << a << endl;
        int b = n / 10;
        cout << b << endl;
        //*this part is complicated*
        return a + result(a + b);
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << result(5126);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return` is not a function. You don't call it like `return(value)`

Comment: What specially do you find confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Taking like a writing test.

1. You call result() function with the value of **5126**
2. Result() function will ask to computer: Is **5126** less than or equal
   to **10**?
3. As you can see it is not, so it will continue to the "else part"
4. Then, it will add the result of the modulus operation of **5126** *modulo
   of* **10** which is **6**, so now, "*a*" is equal to **6**
5. It will print the value of "*a*", `a = 6`
6. Then it will add the result of the division of **5126** *between* **10** which
   is **512.6** (due to it is a *float* and *variable is integer*, the compiler
   will took it as **512**), so now "*b*" is equal to **512**, it will print it.
7. Here is when **recursive is on**, we will call a **imaginary variable
   total** which now have the value of "*a*" which is **6** plus the **result of
   running result()** function with the value of *a plus b* which is **512+6**
8. We enter again in result function but now with *n* as **518**, again,
   Result() function will ask to computer: Is **518** less than or equal to
   **10**?
9. As you can see it is not, so it will continue to the "*else part*"
10. Then, it will add the result of the modulus operation of **518** *modulo
    of* **10** which is **8**, so now, "*a*" *is equal to* **8**
11. It will print the value of "*a*", `a = 8`
12. Then it will add the result of the division of **518** *between* **10** which
    is **51.8** so now "*b*" *is equal to* **51**, it will print it.
13. Our imaginary variable total now have the value of **6** *plus* **8** and the
    result of running result() function with the value of a + b which
    is **51+8**
14. We enter again in result function but now with *n* as **59**, again,
    Result() function will ask to computer: Is **59** *less than or equal to*
    **10**?
15. As you can see it is not, so it will continue to the "*else part*"
16. Then, it will add the result of the modulus operation of **59** *modulo
    of* **10** which is **9**, so now, "*a*" *is equal to* **9** and it will print it.
17. Then, it will add the result of the division of **59** *between* **10** which
    is **5.9** so now "*b*" *is equal to* **5**, it will print it.
18. Our imaginary variable total now have the value of **6+8+9** and the
    result of running result() function with the value of a + b which
    is **5+9**
19. We enter again in result function but now with *n* as **14**, again,
    Result() function will ask to computer: Is **14** *less than or equal to*
    **10**?
20. As you can see it is not, so it will continue to the "*else part*"
21. Then, it will add the result of the modulus operation of **14** *modulo
    of* **10** which is **4**, so now, "*a*" is equal to **4** and it will print it.
22. Then, it will add the result of the division of **14** *between* **10** which
    is **1.4** so now "*b*" is equal to **1**, it will print it.
23. Our imaginary variable total now have the value of **6+8+9+4** and the
    result of running result() function with the value of a + b which
    is **4+1**
24. We enter again in result function but now with *n* as **5**, again,
    Result() function will ask to computer: Is **5** less than or equal to
    **10**?
25. As you can see **5** is less than **10** so now it whill just return *n*
    which is **5** and ***all the recursion will end***.
26. So now ***our imaginary variable total now have the value of
    6+8+9+4+5***, there is no more actions so it will just return the
    total which is **32** and it will be printed.

Hope you understand all explanation, it is easier if you use a writing test, good luck.